# How to check which command was used to load a .sty file?

Tags: package-writing

I have a `.sty` file that may be loaded using the command `\usepackage` (in LaTeX) or the command `\input` (in LaTeX or Plain TeX).

Is there any way that within the `.sty` file to check which command was used to load the file?

Comment: \usepackage will define  the csname `ver@nameofyoursty.sty`. You could test for it.

Comment: You can also check the used format (provided your package should behave the same in LaTeX independent on the used method to load it).

Comment: You might take a look at \@ifpackageloaded.  Presumably it is set by \usepackage, not \input.

Comment: Thanks all, your explanations really solved my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As TeX is a macro expansion language, you cannot know what the 'context' of a macro is: there simply isn't one. Also, `\input` (or `\@@input`) can be used within LaTeX. What you can do is check for the format or some marker macro. For example, in `expl3-generic.sty` we check `\fmtname`

```
\def\tempa{LaTeX2e}
\ifx\fmtname\tempa
  % LaTeX
\else
  % Not LaTeX
\fi
```

A common approach is to check for the existence of something like `\documentclass`

```
\ifx\documentclass\undefined
  % Not LaTeX
\else
  % LaTeX
\fi
```

although this will also be true when things like `miniltx` are loaded. So it depends exactly what you need to know. Some packages are fine with `miniltx`, others perhaps not.

Comment: I see how this would distinguish plain TeX from LaTeX.  But I think OP was asking about distinguishing `\usepackage` from `\input`, both within LaTeX.

Comment: @Teepeemm Which I hope was addressed by my first line: you can't know (you can check for _e.g._ `\ver@<filename>` but of course someone might make that manually and still use `\input`.

Comment: But if someone goes to the trouble of `\makeatletter/other` to manually define `\ver@<filename>`, they know what they're doing and deserve whatever happens.  The comments on the original post also hint at two other ways to check.  Could we spell out exactly how to do so?  If necessary, we could also spell out how those methods could be foiled.